# Fechar o panel quando o mouse sair de cima

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tenho um `Panel` em um `Form` qualquer onde o `Panel` é menor que o `Form`.

Preciso fazer o seguinte: quando o mouse sair de cima do `Panel` o mesmo deve ser fechado como eu poderia fazer isso?

Obs.: estou tentado fazer isso em Windows Form.

Comment: Fechado como? Não tem como fechar um Panel.

Comment: ele deve ficar  "invisivel"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar isso:

```
private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   panel1.Visible = false;
}
```

Mas se tiver um label dentro do painel ele vai sumir caso passe o mause em cima do label.

Para fugir disso você pode fazer assim:

```
private void Form1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = false;
}
```

Como você não colocou o que precisa para ele aparecer de novo eu deixo a resposta até aqui.

Comment: Ele aparece no click do mouse!

Answer (score 1):

Use o evento [`MouseLeave`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave(v=vs.110).aspx) - ele é disparado sempre que o cursor do mouse sair de cima do controle.

```
private void panel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clica no Panel que vc criou no form, pressione F4(pra abrir o painel de propriedades do controle), no painel de propriedades do controle vc vai ter o botão de eventos(Aquele que parece um raio, vai até o evento "MouseLeave" e dê dois cliques(e tem mais coisas com interações de mouse que podem te ajudar).

Automaticamente, será criado o código:

```
private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{ 

}
```

Para "fechar" o Panel, você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
this.panel1.Visible = false;
```

Ficando assim no final:

```
private void panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{   
    this.panel1.Visible = false;  
}
```